# Cannot access to my Svelte component name on Gitlab Pages

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, gitlab-pages

I'm doing a SPA in Svelte. It works locally and on Svelte REPL where the component inside the condition is shown but not when I deploy to Gitlab Pages.

```yaml
  # .gitlab-ci.yml
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
```

In my `App.svelte` I use a `svelte:component` to always render the current `$screen` and only the `footer` component if the screen is `Payments`

```svelte
<script>
    import { screen } from '../store.js' // current screen: Login, Profile, etc
    import Login from './Login.svelte'
    import Menu from '../components/Menu.svelte'

    // Screens with Menu
    const screens_menu = ['Payments']

    // Default screen
    $screen = Login
</script>

<main>
    <svelte:component this={$screen} />
    {#if screens_menu.includes($screen.name)}
        <footer><Menu /></footer>
    {/if}
</main>
```

In my `store.js` I have this

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'
// Current Screen
export let screen = writable(null)
```

**Check same example**

[Working on Svelte REPL.](https://svelte.dev/repl/4f9a95802d6c43b39b4bdf4ff4a6b1f4?version=3.29.4)

**Note**

If I use the component screen itself instead of the variable `name` everything works as expected but now (probably) I'm overloading (importing all the screens). Now, it's only `Payments` but it could be more screens.

```svelte
<script>
    import { screen } from '../store.js'
    import Payments from './Payments.svelte'
    import Menu from '../components/Menu.svelte'
    
    // Screens with Menu
    const screens_menu = [Payments]
    // ...
</script>

<main>
    <svelte:component this={$screen} />
    {#if screens_menu.includes($screen)}
        <footer><Menu /></footer>
    {/if}
</main>
```

Do I need to configure anything extra, anyone experimenting something similiar after deployment?

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: There's no difference in what you're loading with $screen vs $screen.name. How is your store created? What's in store.js?

Comment: Thanks rixo, I've updated my question with `store.js`. I mean loading (importing) each screen/page that has a menu to do the check. Ex: with `const screens_menu = [Payments, Profile, Map, About]` I need to import but with `const screens_menu = ['Payments', 'Profile', 'Map', 'About']` I don't, I just check `$screen.name`

Answer (score 0):

If your store is defined as `writable(null)`, it seems expected to me that you have to guard against the condition where the store's value is null.

Said otherwise, you should probably write your condition like such:

```
    {#if $screen && screens_menu.includes($screen.name)}
        <footer><Menu /></footer>
    {/if}
```

Comment: In that case it wouldn't be possible to render `<svelte:component this={$screen} />` in first place. The error would jump the line before. I'm setting with a router `$screen = Login`. The thing is that it works locally but not when I deploy on Gitlab Pages. I've updated my question with the router.

Comment: `<svelte:component />` supports being given a null value : see [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c6fbc997bc7c493287703e999582e56d?version=3.29.0). Apparently you've got a render cycle where `$screen` is null with the build version, somehow. Just avoiding to crash on this should make it work. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Thank you so much rixo, yes I did but unfortunately it doesn't work. I have added [this working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4f9a95802d6c43b39b4bdf4ff4a6b1f4?version=3.29.4) to my question and the [same code](https://gitlab.com/gengns/svelte-gitlab-pages) to [a not working Gitlab Page example](https://gengns.gitlab.io/svelte-gitlab-pages/) where the footer is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

`$screen.name` after deployment has changed because of the internal refactoring (bundling). Therefore the condition is never met and the `Menu` never shown.

Relying on a function's name in any app - Svelte or not - is a bad idea because can be affected by bundling.

Finally, as proposed in my question, I'm using the components instead of the names. Maybe thanks to tree-shaking there is no overloading.